# How to make GROUP BY query with Many To Many Fields in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, many-to-many

I want to make a request to select the number of total quantity per product.
The models look like this:

```
class Products(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Orders(models.Model):
      product = models.ManyToManyField(Products, through='OrdersQuantities')

class OrdersQuantities(models.Model):
      quantity = models.IntegerField()
      product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

And the SQL query I want to make in Django using `Orders` model

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity) AS qte
FROM products, ordersquantities
WHERE ordersquantities.product_id = product.id
GROUP BY name ORDER BY qte DESC
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Products` queryset with:

```
Products.objects.annotate(
    qte=Sum('ordersquantities__quantity')
).order_by('-qte')
```

The `Products` objects that arise from this queryset, will have an extra attribute `.qte` that contains the sum of the `quantity`s of the related `OrdersQuantities`.

We can also list the `Product`s with the corresponding quantities for a *given* order:

```
Products.objects.filter(
    ordersquantities__order=some_order_object
).annotate(
    qte=Sum('ordersquantities__quantity')
).order_by('-qte')
```

Here we thus will not count `OrdersQuantities` that do not belong to the *`some_order_object`*.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `OrdersQuantity` instead of <s>`OrdersQuantities`</s>.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this using the ```Orders```model?

Comment: @AleckBernard: but it makes no sense to do that. Nowhere in your query it works with the order.

Comment: You can however filter the `QuerySet`, such that it only retrieves the products (and the corresponding quantities) for a given `Order` object.

Comment: @AleckBernard: your `OrdersQuantities` is also missing a `ForeignKey` to the `Order` model.

Comment: @AleckBernard: see edit to determine the products/quantities for a given order.

Comment: I have tried this ```Orders.objects.all().values('product__name').annotate(qte=Sum('product__ordersquantities__quantity')).order_by('-qte')``` but the results were wrong

Comment: @AleckBernard: please do *not* make use of `.values`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: @AleckBernard: if you filter on the order you are interested in, you can see the `Product`s objects (that will contain the name, etc.), together with the total quantity of that product for that order.

Comment: @AleckBernard: can you explain *what* you want (and not *how*). This is probably the XY problem: your real problem is capture some data, but you ask a different question by asking how to translate the SQL query in Django.

Comment: I just want to sum the quantities of ```OrdersQuantities``` and group them by products

Comment: @AleckBernard: then that is what the first query does. It will for each `Products` object have an exta attribute `.qte` that contains the sum of the quanties of the `OrderQuantities`.